# How to export a GridView data into .csv file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a issue while exporting Gridview data into .csv file.I have followed a link to export 
[This link i have follow please check it](http://dotnetask.com/Resource.aspx?Resourceid=668). When I run the application it creates just header names, remaining body fields   always  show null values. Please help me how to export GridView data into .csv file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your GridView use the template fields, and your property «.Text» is always null.

Suggestion: Put a break-point just in «sw.Write(dr.Cells[i].Text);» and check your Cells[i] object. Search for the property you want to put in the file. Probably you will need to do some cast to catch the right value you want.

Ex.: sw.Write(((TextBox)dr.Cells[i].Controls[0]).Text);

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jeison Thank you for giving response i have try this    sw.Write(((TextBox)dr.Cells[i].Controls[0]).Text); to ge tvalues but it showing error like " Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'."

Comment: i am using gridview template fields .